# Check if Android app is a game by packageName

Tags: android, package-name

This is a question that I've not been able to fetch from StackOverflow or directly from Google. Is it maybe because I didn't search with the right words?

Well, anyway:

I'm trying to check if an app is a game by its `packageName`.

What I've researched:

1. [I know the app could be checked if it comes from the Play Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26113429/check-if-android-app-is-installed-by-playstore), but what about if it comes from **any** store?
2. [Inside the `PackageInfo`, there's the feature `PackageManager.FEATURE_GAMEPAD`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) but what about if it doesn't have any GAMEPAD or anything related? just a game of... puzzle for example?.
3. [I know that from API >= 21 you can really check it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15998081/how-to-detect-if-an-android-app-is-a-game), but what about the older ones?

Thank you very much in advance.

Regards.

Rafael.

Comment: How are we supposed to know if an app is a game by its package name? I mean: You have an app called `postman.tracker`. How can you tell if it is a game or a serious app?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough: there's **no way**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm trying to check if an app is a game by its packageName.

By definition, that is impossible. For example, there is no universal definition of what a "game" is.

> I know that from API >= 21 you can really check it

No, you can't, as there is no requirement for a game to have that flag set.

Answer (score 0):

Check the app category in play store
Just parse the page of the play store for that package and get the category it is in. Games have a very distinctive category